# Factorization of a linear map through quotient space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: V\rightarrow W$ be a linear mapping. Let $M$ be a linear subspace such that $M \subset ker(T)$. Let $Q$ be the quotient mapping  $Q:V \rightarrow V/M$ then I have to show there is unique mapping $S: V/M \rightarrow W$ such that $T=SQ$.

Thoughts: Is it a reasonable choice to choose $S(x+M) = T(x+m) = T(x)$ for any coset $x+M$ and any $m \in M$ since $M \subset ker (T)$ or have I drifted down the wrong path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made the good choice and you proved that the map $S$ is well-defined by writing $T(x+m)=T(x)$ for all $x\in V$, $m\in\text{Ker}\,T$. It remains to show that $S$ is linear.

Comment: you mean that S is linear :)?

Comment: Of course! I make an edit.